# Unity Build Failed - Duplicate Class

Tags: unity, android

I'm here struggling for hours to build my game (android) and 'Execution failed for task : checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'

```
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnimatorRes found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar) and androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.1.0.jar)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.zaa found in modules classes.jar (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.0.0:) and classes.jar (:com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.1.0:)
```

... are just two examples of the 486 warnings I'm getting.
Can anyone help a noob out?
Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Worked when I deleted 2 files from Plugins/Android folder.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post your solution as an Answer that can help others. Please be sure to include details of which files you had to delete, or the process that helped you identify that those files needed to be deleted.

Comment: "[...] _and_ the process that helped [...]". Because deleting random files may cause more harm than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this I deleted com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-17.0.0 and androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0 from Plugins/Android folder.

Comment: Basically, you had two versions of the same jar, probably brought it by different packages. The error tells you which two jars have the same class and you just delete the older versioned jar. (I ran into this same problem and this answer helped me by example.) My case was weirder because google renamed the jar rather than versioning them, but a quick search shows the two jars were the same in spite of their rename.